# Switching to UI context in a continuation, using TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, parallel-processing, task, continuations

I'm trying to catch the error which my method throws by using a continuation.  I then want to update the ui of my web forms page which called the tasks.  I'm using the TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() to switch back to the UI thread, but it doesn't seem to work.  Each time I step through, MyMethodWhichThrowsAnError() is called and then the task continuation which doesn't use the UI thread.  The task which calls the UI thread is never hit.

If I change the main task which calls MyMethodWhichThrowsAnError() to use the UI context, then both the continuations are hit.  The code seems right according to the blogs I've found, but it's not working.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    MyMethodWhichThrowsAnError();

});
```

continuation which uses the UI thread:

```
task.ContinueWith(lastTask =>
{
    if (task.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
    {
        label1.Text = "my friendly message";
    }
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

continuation which doesn't use the UI thread:

```
task.ContinueWith(task2 =>
{
    if (task.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
    {
        label1.Text = "my friendly message";
    }
});
```

Comment: With the debugger at your first `ContinueWith` call, is `SynchronizationContext.Current` non-null, and what type is it?